# getStaticProps returning undefined in Nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm working on a blog in Nextjs, and I want it to to fetch all of the blog posts from a directory on build. But no matter what I return with getStaticProps, it always returns undefined in the main component. I have tried it in both next dev and next build.

```js
//import Markdown from "react-markdown";
import styles from "./post.module.css";
import { promises as fs } from "fs";
import matter from "gray-matter";

const Post = ({ post, title, date, summary, image, test }) => {
    console.log(post) //returns undefined
    return (
        <div id={ styles.postcontainer }>
            <div id={ styles.post }>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Post;

export const getStaticPaths = async() => {
    return {
        paths: [...(await fs.readdir("assets/markdown")).map(file => { return { params: { id: file.replace(".md", "") } } }) ],
        fallback: false
      }
};
  

export const getStaticProps = async(context) => {
    const post = await fs.readFile(`assets/markdown/${ context.params.id }.md`, "utf8");
    console.log(post) //success
    return {
        props: {
            post : matter(post).content,
            title : matter(post).data.title,
            date : matter(post).data.date,
            summary : matter(post).data.summery,
            image : `../assets/${ matter(post).data.image }`,
        }
    }
};
```

The markdown file looks like this

```markdown
---
title : test
slug : test
date : 3-9-22
summery : some summery of the post...
image : test.png

---

# Header 1
```

Im pretty sure that the issue isn't with the data == undefined, because when I log it in terminal (inside getStaticProps) it responds with the correct values.

`console.log(post)`

```markdown
---
title : test
slug : test
date : 3-9-22
summery : lorem ipsum
image : test.png

---

# Header 1
```

I've tried

```js
props: {
            test : "testvalue123"
        }
```

but it still returns undefined in the main component. Thanks in advance!

Edit:
The issue was with my _app.js file (not the code above). I had forgotten to add pageProps to the returned component in _app.js.

Comment: What does `matter(post).content` return if you log it to the console inside `getStaticProps`?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
const post = await fs.readFile(`assets/markdown/${ context.params.id }.md`, "utf8");
const result = await post.json();
return {
   
 props: {
        post : result.content,
        title : result.data.title,
        date : result.data.date,
        summary : result.data.summery,
        image : `../assets/${ result.data.image }`,
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using the module "gray-matter" to collect get data from the posts such as title, image, etc... I will add the markdown file to the original post to help with this. Naming "gray-matter" "parse" when importing it is probably a mistake, and I will also update my code to fix that to avoid further confusion. However because the markdown file isn't formatted as a json, `post.json()` doesn't work.